# Pycharm ideavim macro recording not happening while pressing 'q'

Tags: pycharm, vim-plugin, ideavim

I am using Pycharm Community Edition 2017.02 along with the IdeaVim plugin for Vim emulation.

When I press 'q' to record a macro, it is closing the tab instead of starting to record a macro.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Check Shortcut Conflicts settings page:
[image]